# MVC3 Flash data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, codeigniter, session

The codeigniter (PHP) framework support functionality call *FlashData*. Flashdata for those of you who do not know is a session which is only valid for one page request. [Information on Flashdata (half way down the page)](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

I want to know if MVC3 supports a similar function to this?

EDIT::
With the aid of answers below I found the following link which describes the TempData functionality:
[Temp data, ViewBag, View Data in MVC](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called **[TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx)** and does exactly the same thing.

It's also useful to note that you can [implement TempData providers](http://afana.me/post/session-less-controllers-and-TempData-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) so you could do one that didn't require Session.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of "FlashData". You have `TempData` which is there for one request and then you have `ViewData`. The difference between the two are that `TempData` is available if you do a redirect in your application while `ViewData` is only available during the current request. `TempData` is good for scenarios where you use the "post redirect get", prg, pattern.

Comment: I would add that, if you want to do the PRG pattern in Mvc, there's a cool actionfilter in MvcContrib library called "ModelStateToTempData" that makes the implementation of PRG a trivial matter.

Comment: ViewData is not FlashData. CodeIgniter has the concept of ViewData as well see here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html